# Supervisord conf, work with variables?

Tags: supervisord

Can I define `PROJECT_HOME = /home/a/b/c`

and use it later with something like `{{PROJECT_HOME}}` inside supervisord conf?

Comment: ever got an answer to that?

Answer (score -1):

If you have an environment variable named **VARIABLE**. Then inside the supervisord.conf you should use **%(ENV_VARIABLE)s**